# A PGFplots linear regression problem

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots, pgfplotstable, pgfmath

I'm having problems with the linear regression function in PGFplots. The eq given by the package has the signs changed.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}


\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}

\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
    compat=1.3,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$\dfrac{T_{e}-T_{a}}{I_{T}}$ [\si{\kelvin \metre\squared\per\watt}]},
ylabel={Eficiencia instantánea $[-]$},
legend cell align=left,
legend pos=north east]
\addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
    X Y\\
    0.0125613   0.7422\\
    0.0128012   0.7384\\
    0.0130288   0.7217\\
    0.0132965   0.6981\\
    0.0135467   0.6715\\
};
\addlegendentry{Mediciones}
\addplot[color=NavyBlue,mark=*] table[row sep=\\,
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] 
{
    X Y\\
    0.0125613   0.7422\\
    0.0128012   0.7384\\
    0.0130288   0.7217\\
    0.0132965   0.6981\\
    0.0135467   0.6715\\
};
\addlegendentry{Regresión Lineal}
\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
  \hat{\eta_{i}}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressiona}   \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressionb}\frac{\Delta T}{I_{T}}
\end{equation}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Apart from the fact that your document did not compile, you confused the slope with the offset. `\pgfplotstableregressiona` is the slope and `\pgfplotstableregressionb` is the offset. If you correct that, you get

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\usepackage[letterpaper, margin = 1 in]{geometry}
\usepackage[spanish, es-tabla]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table,longtable,x11names]{xcolor}  

\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[H]
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pgfplotsset{width=10cm,
    compat=1.16,
    legend style={font=\footnotesize}}
\begin{axis}[
xlabel={$\dfrac{T_{e}-T_{a}}{I_{T}}$ [\si{\kelvin \metre\squared\per\watt}]},
ylabel={Eficiencia instant\'anea $[-]$},
legend cell align=left,
legend pos=north east]
\addplot[only marks] table[row sep=\\]{
    X Y\\
    0.0125613   0.7422\\
    0.0128012   0.7384\\
    0.0130288   0.7217\\
    0.0132965   0.6981\\
    0.0135467   0.6715\\
};
\addlegendentry{Mediciones}
\addplot[color=NavyBlue,mark=*] table[row sep=\\,
y={create col/linear regression={y=Y}}] 
{
    X Y\\
    0.0125613   0.7422\\
    0.0128012   0.7384\\
    0.0130288   0.7217\\
    0.0132965   0.6981\\
    0.0135467   0.6715\\
};
\addlegendentry{Regresi\'on Lineal}

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\begin{equation}
  \hat{\eta_{i}}=\pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfplotstableregressionb}   
  \pgfmathprintnumber[print sign]{\pgfplotstableregressiona}\frac{\Delta T}{I_{T}}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Sorry, I didn't add \begin{document} and \end{document}. On the other hand, if you say that the x = 0, so the y must be approximately 0.74 and not 1.68

Comment: @MijailLittin You forgot also several packages. And no, it should be `~0.74` for `x=1.26*10^{-2}`.